# React Context API setState callback

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have successfully created a React application using the Context API concept in order to manage global state, but now I've run into a problem that involves performing an action after setState is called in the Context component from a child component.

I have a ListView class based component which has within it a ReactBootstrap NavDropdown component.  The dropdown component has two list items: date and study_name (I'm using it to sort a list either by date or study_name):

`<NavDropdown title="Order By" id="order-nav-dropdown" style={navElementStyle} onSelect={this.onSelect}>`

In the same ListView component, I have the following function to capture the onSelect event of the NavDropdown:

```
onSelect = (e, obj) => {

    var match = obj.target.href.match(/#(.+)$/);

    if(this.context.state[match[1]] !== e){
        this.context.updateState(match[1],  e);
    }
  }
```

In order to manage the Context, I have a separate class based component called SearchContext which has a state:

```
state = {
  order_by: "study_id",  //default value study_id
  sort_by: "desc"        //default value of desc
}
```

In that context component, I have a method called updateState:

```
updateState(key, value){
   this.setState({[key]: value});
}
```

I haven't put all the code of the components here because it's a lot of code, but everything works perfectly.  When I change the drop down list in the component, the state in the SearchContext is updated, and then it is available, for example, when I route out of this component to another component, and then back again.  That was the reason I did this.  I'm using a Router to click on one of the list elements to view that element, but then when I go back to the ListView component, the local state would always be lost I guess because I it was completely re-loading?

Anyways, after much research, Context API was the approach I found, and like I said...it works.  When I route back to ListView, the dropdown lists preserved their list item values.

The problem now is this:

Before I started using the ContextAPI, I was using local state of the ListView component to call setState directly, so I could pass a callback which would then fetch results from a database using Axios (this.updateList is the name of the callback, the callback is not shown here).  It worked like this:

```
onSelect = (e, obj) => {

    var match = obj.target.href.match(/#(.+)$/);

    if(this.state[match[1]] !== e){
        this.setState({[match[1]] :  e},  this.updateList);
    }
  }
```

This allowed me to call this.updateList after the local state was updated.  That worked fine...but now that I've moved the state into the Context component, I cannot use this method because "this" is relative to the child...not the context component.  So I get an undefined method call back.

I've done lots of google searches and I'm narrowing down on this being a problem that can only be solved with hooks, but I don't want to go down that path because there must be an easier way to get this working with the class based approach I'm using.  Unless my approach is completely wrong and I'm not doing this the "React" way, I feel like there should be a way for me to get the same functionality of setState and passing a callback from a child to a parent...

If anyone has any suggestions I would appreciate it.  I'm sure I'll eventually have to learn hooks but the fact that React existed before hooks makes me think there should be a class based approach to this.

Answer (score 1):

OK, after a bit of research, I finally got it working.  Not sure if this will help anyone, but it works for me.

First, in the SearchContext file, I changed the updateState function (which changes the context state) from this:

```
updateState(key, value){
   this.setState({[key]: value});
}
```

to this:

```
  updateState(key, value){

    return new Promise((resolve) =>{
      this.setState({[key]: value}, ()=>{
         resolve('success!');
      });
    })
  }
```

So now, the updateState function returns a promise.

Now, back in the child component, I changed calling the updateState function from this:

```
    if(this.state[match[1]] !== e){
        this.setState({[match[1]] :  e},  this.updateList);
    }
```

to this:

```
    if(this.context.state[match[1]] !== e){
        //The selected state value has changed in the drop down list.
        this.context.updateState(match[1],  e).then((msg) =>{
           console.log(msg)
           this.updateList();
        });
    }
```

...and it works as expected.  The SearchContext state is updated asynchronously, but since I'm returning a promise, I can now wait for the operation to be completed before calling the Axios function which refreshes my list based on the new drop down option.

Pretty cool, I'm very pleased I did not have to re-write everything using hooks and now I understand how to implement a Promise.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to set state in a parent component from a component farther down in the tree via context. This is a totally normal thing to do, and you're on the right track.

Put your `updateState` function in your context object. It will be easiest if you access your context object via the `context` property using `contextType`: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#classcontexttype

Something like this:

```js
import MyContextObject from './MyContextObject'; // defined in its own file

// define your ListView component here

ListView.contextType = MyContextObject
```

Then access your `updateState` function like this:

```js
this.context.updateState({key: value});
```

Note: `contextType` only works with class components (which is what you asked for), and all those articles you're reading that say "you should use hooks" are probably right, Hooks are great! Once you're more comfortable with React, you can look into Redux for app state mgmt: https://redux.js.org

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply to my question.  No problem with calling updateState from the child component.  The problem is setState is asynchronous..but for some reason, if I try to do this from the ListView component:

this.context.updateState({key: value}, () =>{
     console.log('done!');
});

...the call back function (in this case the arrow function that console.logs 'done'...does not work at all.  I need the child to do something AFTER the updateState function updates the context state...and it simply doesn't work.

Comment: @übermensch I think we're getting a little closer to a solution; A few things to clarify: React synthetic events aren't exactly the same as the native browser events. One reason you might not be getting a match is because the synthetic event is expiring. You'd have to call `event.persist()` to store it. In general it's not a good idea to store the actual event like this with react (general guideline: don't use the DOM to identify or store things). Can you refactor to not store the events? Things might be a bit clearer after that.

Comment: I'd be happy to know if I'm doing it the wrong way, but the follow up I posted works for me.  When you say "not getting a match"...are you referring to this part of the code: this.context.state[match[1]] !== e ?  Because if you are, that is not the problem, I'm always getting a match.  The issue was setState does not return a promise, so I was not able to call my Axios method from the child once the state was updated in the parent.